# How to import nested objects in ES6

Tags: javascript

Simple question, I'm trying to use electron and I need to get the `remote` object on the client.

Doing

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote; // Works
```

But

```
import {BrowserWindow} from 'electron/remote' // Does not work
```

New to ES6 classes just unsure why this is not working. Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering how to do deeply nested imports for almost exactly the same reason (pulling from electron/remote). Only difference is that I'm after the save file dialog. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only import from modules. `electron/remote` is not a module, but `remote` is part of the module `electron`, so you can write :

```
import remote from "electron";
```

And then you can do :

```
const {BrowserWindow} = remote;
```

But your first code works fine !
You can read more on import statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use it like this:

```
import {remote} from 'electron'
// do something with remote.BrowserWindow
```